# JSOUP and ListView

Tags: listview, android-listview, jsoup

I'm building a personal app that, using JSOUP, puts the text of certain links into a ListView. For each link there should be a corresponding entry in ListView with the text from that link. When I run the app it successfully parses all of these texts. However, it places all of the text clumped up together in a single ListView entry then does the exact same thing over for consecutive entry. Where am I going wrong? Relevant code below:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

public Elements beer;
public ArrayList<String> beerList = new ArrayList<String>();
private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
private ListView lv;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    new NewThread().execute();
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.simple_list_item_1, R.id.beer_name, beerList);
}

public class NewThread extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... arg) {

        Document doc;
        try {
            doc = Jsoup.connect("URLURLURLURL").userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:5.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/5.0").get();

            beer = doc.select("a[href*=URL.com/URL/]"); 
            beerList.clear();
            for (Element beers : beer) {
                beerList.add(beer.text());
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
    }
```

A visual representation of what I'm currently getting:

- Item1 Item2 Item3 Item4 Item5
- Item1 Item2 Item3 Item4 Item5
- Item1 Item2 Item3 Item4 Item5
- Item1 Item2 Item3 Item4 Item5
- Item1 Item2 Item3 Item4 Item5

vs. what I want to be getting:

- Item 1
- Item 2
- Item 3
- Item 4
- Item 5

Many thanks!

```
activity_main.xml:
         <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >
    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

simple_list_item_1.xml:

```
         <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView android:id="@+id/beer_name"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dip"
        android:textSize="16dip"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>    

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Could you visualize this a little? A picture or just the format of what you want and what you get.

Comment: Added something to the bottom. Hopefully this helps!

Comment: I believe beer.text() is the problem. Try ownText() (wild guess) and if that doesn't work, post actual data so I can provide you a working sample.

Comment: Sorry for the late response. Where do I place the ownText? I've played with a few combinations but the syntax seems to still be off.

Comment: Could you post some sample of the data? I want what you parse (html). Just a sample, or even fake data but with the same format.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/iCZzzryG (just trying to keep the fluff off of here!) the URL is in the title.

Comment: How re u printing your arraylist,try beerList.add(beer.text() +"\n");

Comment: The "\n" adds a linebreak after all of the beers are listed. So it looks like "Item1 Item2 Item3 Item4 Item5 LINEBREAK."

I've got two layout .xml which are being added to the bottom of the code in the OP. This could be where I'm messing up a bit, too.

Comment: check below for answer

Comment: Many thanks again, Immanuel. And to you, alkis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
for (Element beers : beer) {
                    beerList.add(beer.text());
                }
```

to

```
for (Element beers : beer) {
                    beerList.add(beers.text()+"\n");
                }
```

u miss **s** in the beer

**Try this**

```
  public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    public Elements beer;
    public ArrayList<String> beerList = new ArrayList<String>();
    private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
private ListView lv;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    new NewThread().execute();
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.simple_list_item_1, R.id.beer_name, beerList);
}

public class NewThread extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... arg) {

        Document doc;
        try {
            doc = Jsoup.connect("URLURLURLURL").userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:5.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/5.0").get();

            beer = doc.select("a[href*=URL.com/URL/]"); 
            beerList.clear();
            for (Element beers : beer) {
                beerList.add(beers.text()+"\n");
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
    }
```

Comment: is not ur fault its just a tiny error like typo mistake ...u miss s in the beer